# Disable automatic selection on taphold in iOS6

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios6, kendo-ui

I'm having an issue with KendoUI charts which started occurring on iOS 6 devices, which I have reproduced in Safari, Chrome and Mercury.

When a user performs a "taphold" action (touching the screen and keeping the finger pressed for about a second) over an element, the element is highlighted in blue and the "copy/select/select all" context menu is brought up, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

This seems to occur for any type of element so it is not necessarily a KendoUI issue, but in case anyone else has encountered this, I would like to know if it is possible to somehow disable this feature. I've tried using the [jQuery .disableSelection()](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/) method, but to no avail.

The reason for needing to fix this is that my app has some functionality bound to the jQuery mobile "taphold" event when performed on a chart, and the selection of the chart or one of its elements, along with the context menu appearing, can be distracting and confusing for the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the css rule `-webkit-user-select`:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

Comment: I would propose the same approach as Pablo.